# Could it be (not set) in Google Analytics due to not always passed parameter

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I observe lots of data going to (not set) instead of to the actual values.
I suspect that's because I'm not always passing particular parameter to each event log.

Currently I have a single event named "Comment" and 2 different metrics (dimensions) - "LoadComments" and "PostComment". For both the Values are "Successful" | "Failed"

```
// How I log when user post a comment   
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("Comment") {
   param("PostComment", "Successful" | "Failed");
}

// How I log when user load new page in comments screen
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("Comment") {
   param("LoadComments", "Successful" | "Failed" respectively);
}
```

I have "PostComment" registered as a custom dimension but still in Google Analyics Dashboard I see it like:

[image]

Since it would take lot of time to test on production by uploading new version, could anyone confirm if the **(not set)** here is because I'm reusing "Comment" event name and NOT always passing
"PostComment" / "LoadComments" so on my screenshot above could be said (not set) is mixed number of all times I called the methods for posting comment / loading comments?

Should I in such case introduce brand new event name ("PostComment", "LoadComments")?

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the custom parameter dimension is an empty string which will also be evaluated as (not set). So yes, not always passing "PostComment" / "LoadComments" would set the value to (not set).